# "cannot find symbol" error. Something wrong with ShowMessageDialog method?

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class WelcomeInMessageDialogBox{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JOptionPane.ShowMessageDialog(null,"Welcome to Java!");
    }
}
```

Why it reported that in line 5 cannot find symbol?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does a "Cannot find symbol" or "Cannot resolve symbol" error mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-or-cannot-resolve-symbol-error-mean)

Comment: That solves my question, thanks. It turns out that "ShowMessageDiaglog" should be "showMessageDiaglog"